# Officer's Name In Women In Black

Tags: names, grimm

What was the officer's name that was stationed outside Nick and Juliette's house at the end of season one? He was knocked unconscious on their porch by Akira Kimura.

Answer (score 3):

The [IMDB page](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2383907/) for that episode lists three police officers (other than Nick, Hank and Captain Renard):

- Sgt. Wu played by Reggie Lee
- Sgt. Franco played by Robert Blanche
- Officer #1 played by D'Emmanuel Ball

I'd have to rewatch the episode to check (which I wouldn't be able to do until later) but for now the best I can say is that it's very likely to be either Sgt. Franco or the mysterious Officer #1.

Comment: Sgt. Franco is one of the officers that enters the house while the officer is down on the porch. There are several other uncredited officers that enter as well. I wish there was better crediting of background actors...